# Finding mode in vector with strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, iteration

I have to solve a task so it prints the min, the max and the mode of a set of strings. First I store the strings in a vector, than I sort them and then I print the first and the last of the elements of the vector, which is fine. But I have hard times finding the mode of them. Here is the code I wrote.

```
#include<stdafx.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    vector<string>words;

    cout << "Please enter some words. When finished, just enter 'stop'.\n";

    string ant;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while (cin >> ant) {
        if (ant != "stop") {
            words.push_back(ant);
                           }
        else
            break;
                        }

    sort(words.begin(), words.end());

    cout << "The min of the entered words is " << words[0] << "\n";
    cout << "The max of the entered words is " << words.back() << "\n";



}
```

So far this is good. It does the job as I want. But the problem comes when I have to find the mode of the strings. I found some code on the net for finding mode of given integers and it works for integers. I tried to modify it for strings but I could not get it to work. Here is the code:

```
for (string test = 0; test<words.size(); ++test) {
    if (words[test] == words[test + 1]) {
        count++;
                                        }
    else if (words[test] != words[test + 1]) {
        if (count>max) {
            max = count;
            mode = words[test];
                        }

        count = 0;

                                            }

                                                }
```

This gives me a lot of errors, I do not know where to begin. I think the problem is that this is not a proper way to make iteration of strings. I found some explanations about iteration of strings, but its so confusing for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ahhhh, my eyessss!!!!!

Comment: You are very close! Change `string test = 0;` to `int test = 0;` and that should get rid of most of the errors.

Comment: `words[test + 1]` is UB here, your program might crash, or your computer might grow legs and duel your girlfriend.

Comment: Well I don't believe it will grow legs, but it certainly does not finds mode of the given strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your modified version of the algorithm that finds the mode of the entered words is correct. The only thing i can say about it is, `count` and `max` are keywords in C++ so you'd have to change the names to avoid undesired effects. Also, don't forget to declare `mode` as type `string`.

With little modification of your code, this works;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <map>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string>words;

    cout << "Please enter some words. When finished, just enter 'stop'.\n";

    string ant;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while (cin >> ant) {
        if (ant != "stop") {
            words.push_back(ant);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    sort(words.begin(), words.end());

    cout << "The min of the entered words is " << words[0] << "\n";
    cout << "The max of the entered words is " << words.back() << "\n";

    //Finding the mode of the entered words
    int _count = 0;
    int _max = 0;
    string mode;
    for (unsigned int test = 0, j = 1; test<words.size(); test++, j++) {
        if (words[test] == words[j]) {
            _count++;
        }
        else if (words[test] != words[j]) {
            if (_count>_max) {
                _max = _count;
                mode = words[test];
            }

            _count = 0;

        }
    }

    cout << "The mode of the entered words is " << mode;

}
```

Comment: This does not work, it compiles, but after I enter the strings and hit stop it crushes.

Comment: Doesn't crash over here. Try doing this `test++` instead of `++test` in the for loop of the mode algorithm

Comment: Same again, btw I am using Visual Studio 2015 and also I have IDE by bloodshed C++ version 5.1. It crushes in the both IDEs. Which IDE do you use? I guess @George is right.

Comment: @BazeJakimovski It probably crashes because `words[test + 1]` is an attempt to access the vector out of bounds.

Comment: @NanaOsaberima At some point you'll effectively try and access `words[words.size()]` which is as pointed out UB, so the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Corey I admit that logically, my earlier code should access the vector out of bounds but the code worked fine. I think it had to do with my compiler. I have modified my answer by changing the loop anyway.

Comment: @NanaOsaberima I think the code is now logically incorrect, the fix was probably your original code but `test<words.size()` -> `test<words.size()-1`